# Issue with changing boolean value permently in TIC-80

Tags: lua, boolean, game-development

I recently ran into an issue where when I click on a object it activates for as long as the left mouse button is clicked. I would like for it to open, and stay open until I click it again.

I am using bm.clicked as a boolean value to determine if a menu should be open or not.
The goal was for the value to remain true after being clicked until it is clicked again, making it false.

```
game_meta={
    rage_amo=1,
    p_balence=25,
    playing=true
}

function super_check(a,b,c,v)
    if (a==v) or (b==v) or (c==v) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function check_collision_p(x,y)
    t=mget(x,(y+8))
    if (t==1) or (t==17) or (t==33) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function check_collision_a(x,y)
    t=mget(x,(y-8))
    t2=mget((x+8),y)
    t3=mget((x-8),y)
    if super_check(t,t2,t3,48) or super_check(t,t2,t3,49) or super_check(t,t2,t3,50) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function check_mouse_interact(x,y,bx,by,mx,my,ml,ox,oy)
    if (ml and (mx>=(x-ox) and mx<=(bx-ox)) and (my>=(y-oy) and my<=(by-oy))) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function player()
    px,py,pl=mouse()
    if pl then
        circb(px, py, 2, 10)
    end
end

function down_block(x,y)
    db_meta={
        x=x,
        y=y,
        bx=(x+8),
        by=(y+8),
        respawn=false,
        g_break=false,
        falling=false,
        cost=10
    }
    spr(48,db_meta.x,db_meta.y)
    if check_mouse_interact(db_meta.x,db_meta.y,db_meta.bx,db_meta.by,px,py,pl,4,4) then
        db_meta.falling=true
        print(db_meta.falling)
    end
end

function init_ui()
    -- healthbar
    rectb(15,5,150,10,1)
    rect(16,6,game_meta.rage_amo,8,2)
    print("RAGE-O-METER",58,7)
    -- build menu button
    rectb(175,5,55,10,14)
    rect(176,6,53,8,13)
    print("BUILDINGS",177,7)
    x=176
    y=6
    clicked=false
    bx=(x+53)
    by=(y+8)
    if check_mouse_interact(x,y,bx,by,px,py,pl,0,0) then
        clicked=true
        print(clicked)
        rectb(175,18,55,50,14)
        rect(176,19,53,48,13)
    end
    if check_mouse_interact(x,y,bx,by,px,py,pl,0,0) and clicked==true then
        clicked=false
    end
end

function non_player(x,y)
    np={
        x=x,
        y=y,
        ix=x,
        iy=y,
        jumping=false,
        alive=true,
        on_tile=false,
        c_lvl=0
    }
    spr(257,np.x,np.y)
end

function TIC()
    cls(0)
    map(0,0,30,17,0,0,0)
    player()
    down_block(32, 32)
    init_ui()
    non_player(32,96)
end
```

Comment: looks like you are calling `init_ui()` on every tic which is setting clicked to false and only setting it back to true if you are clicking, so seems like it is working as you wrote it. Maybe you should only be calling init once and have another function that checks mouse interaction every tic? Also all the vars you are setting in the functions should probably be local, as they seem to be global unless TIC-80 has changed scoping or unless you want them global.